# How do you add a song to the end of an ExoPlayer playlist when it reaches STATE_ENDED and start playback from that added song?

Tags: android, androidx, exoplayer, android-media3

I am trying to wait for ExoPlayer to finish playing a playlist and then append a song to the end of the playlist and starting the playlist from that added song.

I tried doing this, but it does not work:

```
        override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
            super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
            if (playbackState == STATE_ENDED) {
                playerHolder.getPlayer().addMediaItem(
                    playerHolder.getPlayer().currentMediaItem!!
                )
                playerHolder.getPlayer().play()
            }
        }
```

Nothing is played after that code is run.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you play a song when ExoPlayer reaches STATE\_ENDED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77862587/how-do-you-play-a-song-when-exoplayer-reaches-state-ended)

Comment: you posted nearly the same question 3 min earlier

Comment: That question was regarding how to repeat the same song without using the loop once feature. Plus, the way I found in that question is kind of hacky involving replacing the playlist entirely.

Comment: In this question, I specifically want to keep the playlist in tact, append to the end of it, and play the appended media item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason the code in the question does not work is because the `playWhenReady` field of the player is true when in the callback, so `play()` has no effect. A seek call is needed to start the playback. The following code does what was trying to be done.

```
        override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
            super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
            if (playbackState == STATE_ENDED) {
                val player = playerHolder.getPlayer()
                player.addMediaItem(
                    player.currentMediaItem!!

                )
                player.seekTo(
                    player.mediaItemCount - 1,
                    C.TIME_UNSET
                )
            }
        }
```